# 64-bit system, GINT_TO_POINTER(i) / GPOINTER_TO_INT(p)

Tags: c, gtk, glibc

I'm having the hardest time getting an integer passed to a callback function, since the last argument of `g_signal_connect` is required to be a pointer.  Here is where I connect the signal to the callback:

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
{

    ...
    gtk_widget_set_events(tab_ebs[i],GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (tab_ebs[i]), "button_press_event", G_CALLBACK (tab_clicked_cb), GINT_TO_POINTER(i));

}
```

and here is the callback:

```
void tab_clicked_cb (gpointer p)
{
    printf("tab #%d clicked\n", GPOINTER_TO_INT(p));
}
```

What I get in stdout, are statements such as:

```
tab #6578976 clicked
tab #6579264 clicked
tab #6579552 clicked
tab #6579840 clicked
```

When I only have ten tabs.  How can I pass an integer to a callback fcn on a 64 bit system?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nos got me half way there.  Turns out I was also missing an argument for the event in my callback function. Here is the form that worked:

```
void tab_clicked (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *ev, gpointer p)
{
    printf("tab #%d clicked\n", GPOINTER_TO_INT(p));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your callback function is likely wrong, most Gtk callback handlers passes the widget that originated the event as the first parameter to the callback function. So it should be e.g.

```
void tab_clicked_cb (GtkWidget *widget, gpointer p)
{
    printf("tab #%d clicked\n", GPOINTER_TO_INT(p));
}
```

Edit, The Gtk [docs](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/GtkWidget.html) are not at all clear on what it's callback handler is for the button_press_event, the docs read as the callback handler for button_press_event doesn't receive any arguments.

Comment: thanks for your response.  I changed the `tab_clicked_cb` the way you described, but now I get responses that look like: tab #7334608 clicked.

Comment: If you look at the documentation for `button-press-event` ([here](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-button-press-event)) then you can see what arguments the handler is supposed to receive.